# What is the proper goose import syntax

Tags: python, import, goose

The goose install places goose in the python-goose directory. When I try to import goose at the IDLE prompt I get:

```
>>> from goose import Goose

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from goose import Goose
ImportError: No module named goose
```

Because goose is installed in the python-goose directory I believe the import syntax should be:
from python-goose.goose import Goose
however when I run this I get the following syntax error message:

```
>>> from python-goose.goose import Goose
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions on how to properly import goose would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `setup.py install` yet?

Comment: Hello, Yes I ran setup.py install during the install. The install seemed to work correctly. If I initiate IDLE from my root directory I get the module not found error. However if I change the directory to python-goose and then open IDLE and then import goose I get an error message telling me that the BeautifulSoup module cannot be found. The fact that while in the python-goose directory the import can proceed far enough to look for BeautifulSoup indicates that goose has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy your **goose**  directory `/goose-extracor/goose`  and paste it with goose-extractor and python packages directories

```
/goose-extractor
/goose
```

And import it

```
from goose import Goose
```